# remove rows from data frame depending on (date) order and Id

Tags: python, pandas

These are my haves:

```
haves = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '2', '2'],
                   'date': ['2011-01-01', '2011-01-03', '2011-01-03'],
                   'some_value': [1, 1, 2], 
                   'flag': [0, 0, 1]})

print(haves)   
  id        date  some_value  flag
0  1  2011-01-01           1     0
1  2  2011-01-03           1     0
2  2  2011-01-03           2     1
```

I would like to remove rows with flag = 0, if there is a "duplicate" w.r.t. same date and id. Hope this makes sense? So using this small simple example, my wants are as follows:

```
wants = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '2'],
                   'date': ['2011-01-01', '2011-01-03'],
                   'some_value': [1, 2]}) 

print(wants)
  id        date  some_value
0  1  2011-01-01           1
1  2  2011-01-03           2
```

Can this be achieved in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) chained by `|` for bitwise OR by second condition for test not equal by `0` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), pass masks to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
df = haves[~haves.duplicated(['id','date'], keep=False) | haves['flag'].ne(0)]
print(df)
  id        date  some_value  flag
0  1  2011-01-01           1     0
2  2  2011-01-03           2     1
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove `flag` after testing:

```
df = haves[~haves.duplicated(['id','date'], keep=False) | haves.pop('flag').ne(0)]
print(df)
  id        date  some_value
0  1  2011-01-01           1
2  2  2011-01-03           2
```

**Details**:

```
print(~haves.duplicated(['id','date'], keep=False))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

print (haves.pop('flag').ne(0))
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: flag, dtype: bool

print (~haves.duplicated(['id','date'], keep=False) | haves.pop('flag').ne(0))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks - so this is quite simple in Python (sorry more of a R background). so the first means keep all not duplicate or is it is a duplicate keep the ones where flag = 1? Thanks.

Comment: @cs0815 it means keep all not duplicated rows OR if duplicated rows then only if flag=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with multiple conditions.

The easiest is to **keep** the rows that don't match either of the conditions.

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` to identify all duplicates, and [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for unequality to 0:

```
# is the row not a duplicate?
m1 = ~haves[['id', 'date']].duplicated(keep=False)
# is the row not having a 0 flag?
m2 = haves['flag'].ne(0)

# if either condition True then keep, else drop
haves[m1|m2] #.drop('flag', axis=1) # uncomment to drop "flag" column
```

output:

```
  id        date  some_value  flag
0  1  2011-01-01           1     0
2  2  2011-01-03           2     1
```